# QGIS: Add islands

Tags: qgis, multipart

I am failing to achieve to add islands to my polygons. I want these islands to be part of other polygons and not their own ones (I have for example a function which calculates the middle point of a polygon, which then does not make sense).

I have a feature, I selected it, go into editing mode, I select the main polygon with the selection tool and click on "Add part". But this fails with the message "Add part: Could not add part. This layer does not support multipart geometries"

[image]

Comment: What is your QGIS version? Recent QGIS versions don't support multipart geometry in GeoPackage files, it is a new bug. See details here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/54762

Answer (score 2):

Convert your layer to a multipolygon type by exporting it accordingly, then add the islands. Choose the geometry type instead of leaving the export settings on "auto", and force multi.

[image]

Comment: Which import option should I choose? QGIS Layer style file? And then import it again?

Comment: Right click layer > export - it will be loaded outomatically to QGIS. Otherwise, the saved file can be loaded as any other data to QGIS.

Comment: "Save as". Layer definition files only contain a link to the shape file/geopackage and its symbology @Hemmelig

Comment: Ok, I clicked Saved as, choose Polygon and also the multipart checkmark. I now have a new object in my layer menu. However, I still cannot draw islands. If I choose my own layer, I still get the error of not having multiparts available, if I click on the new layer, I cannot even access the advanced digitising toolbar (its greyed out)

Comment: The multipart geometry editing worked good in QGIS 3.12.3 version. If it's urgent, you can download 3.12.3 version standalone installer from the QGIS website and install it without deleting your current version.

Comment: Unfortunately not for my OS, but thanks for the hint. This is very weird!

Comment: @Hemmelig which file type did you save to? Geopackage or shape?

Comment: CSV. Lol. Well. That explains a lot. But what is actually the correct one to choose here?

Comment: As I asked: "Geopackage or shape"?